# Running Gherkin Feature in Visual Studio Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, gherkin

I am trying to set up and run a simple test scenario where i open google in chrome and search for google and click the first link. I coming from this with zero knowledge on any of this tools.

I am using SpecFlow, Gherkin and Selenium.

I have currently created my .feature file and the steps.cs file:

SpecFlowFeature.feature:

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers

Scenario Outline: Browese to Google page
    Given I am on the Google home page
    When I type <search> into textbox
    Then I should see link for Google

    Examples: 
        | Search     |
        | Google     |
```

SpecFlowFeatureSteps.cs:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowFeatureSteps
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void InitScenario()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void TearDownScenario()
        {
            driver.Dispose();
        }

        [Given(@"I am on the Google home page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnTheGoogleHomePage()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.co.uk");
        }

        [When(@"I type (.*) into textbox")]
        public void WhenITypeIntoTextbox(string p0)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("google");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).Click();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see link for Google")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeLinkForGoogle()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Googlelkj;lkhpbgpiugfytdturwxesugh;k'k#';")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

When ever I try to click 'Run All' in the Test Explorer, it doesn't seem to discover any tests.

Comment: Did you try clean the solution and rebuild? Also which testing framework you are using Mstest or NUnit?

Comment: I ran the Clean and then Rebuild. However now I don't even get the output that state no test have been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the unit test provider is NUnit. I assume you are using MSTest. 
You need to change the default adapter in the app.config file as

```
<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
```